# Allow any GroupID for Vaadin business app starter

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

If I try to create a new vaadin app with the [business app starter](https://vaadin.com/start/v14/business-app) and use my own GroupID, I always got the error `Group ID must start with org.vaadin.addons.` I would expect, that I can use any valid java package name, especially because I have the PRO subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug. The restriction should only be in place for the add-on starter to prevent dependency confusion when dependencies with the same coordinates are found from both the Maven and the Vaadin add-on repositories.

I've informed the relevant people.